# How to view code from 'import' easily (eg. Django code) in visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am learning and building a Python application within a docker container.  My editor is visual studio code.  Whilst learning, I like to click around to see what other code is doing, to help understand it best, but am unsure the best process whilst working with Python.

For example, I am importing the 'os' library, but in that library there are lots of capabilities, and it would be good to be able to delve in and see what they are.

Any process recommendations would be greatly appreciated to help with my learning here.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: For any module included in the standard library, such as `os`, would it be easier to have a look at the Standard Library Documentation ((https://docs.python.org/3.6/) or (https://docs.python.org/2.7/))?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if you let your cursor stay after a statement like `import os`, VS Code will show you a brief description of the module and what functions or sub-modules you can further import from there. It's part of the [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) feature.

Comment: @JST99 that is what I am after I think. Especially as I can then ctrl+click the item to see the full code. My only issue appears to be that it isn't loading in the django code. I imagine this is due to all the libraries installed being in my docker container, so will see if installing them to my host python helps.

Comment: That was it, installed on my host, restarted VS Code, and intellisense appears to pick it up.  This will help me a lot with my style of learning.  Thanks for the help

Comment: @retrodans Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help clarify the solution from the comments above, this is what I needed to do to get intellisense working for me in the way I needed.

1. Ensure your host machine has all the modules/libraries installed you are going to do (this is on top of your docker container having them, as VS Code cannot see them).  To do this on the site I am working on was `python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Note: This did come up with some bugs, but a quick google helped with these, and were generally around installing `python3.6-dev` and `libmysqlclient-dev`.

2. Ensure VS Code is pointing to the python version you are using (for example, I set mine to python3.6).  This can be done in the bottom-left menu options

Once these steps are done, you should be able to hover over all imports and classes to get some info, and also ctrl+click will take you into the code to look around it.